# How do I get a list of accepted suggestions using the Google drive api?

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I want to get the author of the suggestion and the text that has been changed.

I tried the driveactivity api. There is a comment id and a link to the author. But I do not know what to do with it.

My code:

```
drive = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
driveactivity = build('driveactivity', 'v2', credentials=credentials)

results = driveactivity.activity().query(body={
    'itemName': f'items/1al4YzWZT2G6QUVbcVUHa_qbT41IoK6i8RKiyt0ItQS8',
    'pageSize': 10
}).execute()
activities = results.get('activities', [])
for a in activities:
    for t in a['targets']:
        comment_id = t['fileComment']['legacyCommentId']
        try:
            results = drive.comments().get(
                fileId='1al4YzWZT2G6QUVbcVUHa_qbT41IoK6i8RKiyt0ItQS8',
                commentId=comment_id,
                fields='*',
                includeDeleted=True,
            ).execute()
            print(results)
        except HttpError as e:
            print(e)
```

I got 'Comment not found' for all activities.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand your expected value from `Thanks for answer, but I need accepted suggestions. In your sample, only comments are returned.`. My proposed script returns the resolved comments. But, it seems that this is not your expected value. So, in this case, I have to delete my answer. Because I don't want to confuse other users. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again.

Comment: Made different test, and I was unable to list the suggestions in Google Drive files. You might need to make a feature request [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/support#developer_product_feedback).